# Uubuntu 18.04 LTS AD domain joining

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM client and wants to join to AD domain, I have followed realmd and SSD to join the machine to domain.

It was successful, it has joined to one particular domain, where I have multiple DC and we want to clone this image for further use.

What is the best approach and is there any way to configure multiple domains to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for a clone is to NOT be joined to any domain (same applies for Windows clients also). When a computer is joined to a domain a new computer account, its SID and relevant dns records have to be created. So it cannot be done to a clone used for replication. Each replica will consider itself as the original computer account of the clone in the domain. It'll be a mess.

Comment: Thank you Sir, the setup is through horizon view, we have to create a golden image with few packages part of core build. Could you suggest how to proceed if the machine needs to be joined to the Windows domain? Regards.

Comment: Realmd and sssd should be fine. Besides you've already tested it. If you want to authenticate to multiple domains you should go server side, not client side: Trusted domains. It's not possible for a workstation to join multiple domains concurrently.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a possibility to give all the domain users a sudo privilege...not specific to group?

Comment: I got the solution for adding all domain users to ubuntu domain...%Domain\ Users ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL.  Thank you all for helping me :)